# Which middleware to use if I want the route to be accessible by guests, authenticated users and everyone else?

Tags: php, laravel

At first I decided to organize my routes like I have in the code given below. However, I quickly realized that I couldn't access the routes in the group that uses middleware guest as soon as I log in. Does that mean that routes which I want to be accessible by anyone no matter whether they're logged in or not should not be in any middleware group?

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function(){
        Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index')->name('home');
        Route::get('/image/{id}', 'PagesController@specificImage')->name('specificImage');
        Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@contact')->name('contact');
        Route::get('/tags', 'PagesController@tags')->name('tags');
        Route::get('/tags/{tagName}', 'PagesController@specificTag')->name('specificTag');
        Route::get('/albums', 'PagesController@albums')->name('albums');
        Route::get('/albums/{albumId}/{albumName}', 'PagesController@specificAlbum')->name('specificAlbum');
        Route::post('/signup', 'UsersController@signUp')->name('signup');
        Route::post('/signin', 'UsersController@signIn')->name('signin');
        Route::post('/sendmail', 'UsersController@sendMail')->name('sendmail');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
        Route::get('/upload', 'PagesController@upload')->name('upload');
        Route::get('/logout', 'UsersController@logOut')->name('logout');
        Route::get('/imageDelete/{imageId}', 'ImagesController@deleteImage')->name('deleteImage');
        Route::get('/deleteTag/{tagId}', 'TagsController@deleteTag')->name('deleteTag');
        Route::post('/imageUpload', 'ImagesController@uploadImage')->name('imageUpload');
        Route::post('/albumUpload', 'AlbumsController@uploadAlbum')->name('albumUpload');
        Route::post('/createTag', 'TagsController@createTag')->name('createTag');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right. If it's exposed to everyone, why would you want to leave it in a auth group :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove auth middleware from the route group

Answer (score 0):

Correct! Get rid of the guest middleware, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Just Do not use any middleware.